# Generate list of all DNS records in specified subnet

Tags: powershell, dns

I need to generate a list of all DNS records for a specified subnet. Is there a way to do this using either the powershell DNS cmdlets, DNSCMD, or anything else, that isn't the very slow way that I am currently using?

I'm enumerating the host names in `17.(7,8,9).162.(16-238)`.

```
$HostList = @()

ForEach ($a in 7..9) { 
    ForEach ($b in 16..238) {
        $DNSCheck = Resolve-DNSName "17.$a.162.$b"
        $HostList += ($DNSCheck.NameHost)
    }
}

Write-Host $HostList
```

What I've ended up using - Many thanks to Ansgar.

```
$ZoneName = "some.domain"
$DNSHost = "dnsserver"

$Hosts = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $ZoneName -ComputerName $DNSHost -RRType 'A' |? { 
    $Address = $_.RecordData.IPV4Address.ToString()
    $LastOctet = $Address.Split(".")[-1]
    $Address -like "17.[7-9].162.*" -and $LastOctet -in 16..238
}

ForEach ($H in $Hosts) {
    Write-Host $H.HostName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PowerShell DNS cmdlets and borrowing code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8372629/1630171) you could do something like this:

```
$zone  = 'example.com'
$range = '17.7.162.16', '17.7.162.238'

function Addr2UInt($addr) {
  $bytes = $addr.GetAddressBytes()
  [array]::Reverse($bytes)
  [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($bytes, 0)
}

$addrFrom = Addr2UInt ([Net.IPAddress]::Parse($range[0]))
$addrTo   = Addr2UInt ([Net.IPAddress]::Parse($range[1]))

Get-DNSServerResourceRecord $zone -RRType 'A' | ? {
  $addr = Addr2UInt $_.RecordData.IPv4Address;
  $addrFrom -le $addr -and $addr -le $addrTo
}
```

`IPAddress` objects can't be compared using operators like `-le`, but since IP(v4) addresses are basically 32-bit numbers you can convert the bytes of an address to a number for comparison:

```
$bytes = $addr.GetAddressBytes()
(($bytes[0] * 256 + $bytes[1]) * 256 + $bytes[2]) * 256 + $bytes[3]
```

The [`ToUInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method provides a more elegant way to do this conversion (makes it more obvious what's happening, too), but since the method expects the Least Significant Byte at the lowest index the array must be reversed first.

The function just wraps the conversion code for convenience, because I need it at 3 places in the script.

Comment: Thanks. I can't test this until next week. But could you please explain the purpose of the function?

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Very informative. I'll update my question with what I've ended up doing. It's essentially a simplified version of what you've done, as I may not always be managing the script I wanted to keep it simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way I found

```
$Zone = YourDomain.local
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $Zone -RRType A | Where-Object {$_.RecordData.ipv4address -like "192.168.39.*"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this GridView and filter for your IP-Addresses

```
$server = "Your_DNS_Server"
$record = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -ComputerName $server -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType
$record | Select DomainName,RecordData,OwnerName | Sort-Object -Property {[System.Version]$_.RecordData} | Out-GridView
```

Sorting IP-Addresses is done by [System.Version]

```
[system.version]("17.7.162.238")
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
17     7      162     238
```